# Discrete method to determine when 2 sine waves of differing frequency and start time are both zero at once

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I'm aware that I could toss this into wolfram alpha and get an answer using the sine function, but assuming I have all of my data in integers, it should be solvable as them as well.

So I've got two waves, and they'll always have integer wavelengths.  For my example, it's a 3 wavelength wave and a 4 wavelength wave.  In the simplest case of both starting at time 0 sec, they are both 0 at the start and every 12 seconds afterward.  Using the lcm to determine these crossing points works in every case I think, but if they start at different times it can only predict the frequency of them both being zero but not when it starts.

For instance, if the 3 length wave starts at time 1, and 4 length at time 0, they both are 0 at time 4 then every 12 afterward.  But if the 4 length starts at time 2 and the 3 length at time 1, they are both 0 at time 10 and every 12 afterward.

What is the method to determine that first time they will both be 0 together?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: doesn't work for coprime integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a solution to equations of the form:

```
sin((2π*A)(x-B)) == 0
```

and

```
sin((2π*C)(x-D)) == 0
```

By multiplying, note also that:

```
sin(2πAx - 2πAB) == 0
```

and similarly

```
sin(2πCx - 2πCD) == 0
```

Or:

```
Ax - AB == 0
Cx - CD == 0
```

Which provides the following, totally non-shocking values where these functions are zero:

```
x = B + 2π/(2π*A) * k
x = D + 2π/(2π*C) * k
```

Where K is an integer.

Since you're restricting yourself to functions with values where the wavelength is an integer, the values of 1/A and 1/C are similarly guaranteed to be integers.  So this simplifies even further:

```
x = B mod a
x = D mod c
```

Where a and c are the frequencies here.

You can pick your favorite form of solving simultaneous modular equations, of which I will demonstrate the easiest one:

```
x = B + k*a
B+ k*a = D mod c
k * a = D - B mod c
k = (a^-1M) (D-B) mod c
k = (a^-1M) (D-B) + j*c
x = B + a*(a^-1M)*(D-B) + (a*j-c)
x = B + a*(a^-1M)(D-B) mod ac
```

Note that a^-1m is the modulo inverse of a mod c, which you will have to calculate with the extended euclidean algorithm.  (I'll omit this since the value is very small for your example):

```
x = 1 + 3(3)(0-1) mod ac
x = -8 mod ac
```

Given some value like this you can take the right side mod ac in the script and get the correct first value; however note that some scrub languages like Javascript will allow negative results with absolute value less than ac.

So you want something like:

```
( ( (B + a*(a^-1M)*(D-B) ) % ac) + ac ) % ac)
```

With  a^-1M being the modulus inverse of a in c.  Your function should also puke if a%c == 0 or c%a == 0 since these waves will never intersect

Comment: It looks like your function overall could be simplified to ((AB - CD) / (A - C)) % LCD.  I'll experiment with some values and see if it works out ok...

Comment: Now that I think of it, when both of the frequencies are positive integers there are intersections at every integer.  Did you mean frequencies of 1/3 hz and 1/4 hz?

Comment: If I use 3 Hz starting at time 2 and 4 Hz at time 0, I get 1/2.  So something isn't quite right...

Comment: Isn't the first equation in this solution satisfied when the 2 waves cross at any value, not just at `0` as the question asks ?

Comment: Yeah, now that I look at this I think that both the problem I've solved and the described problem aren't quite right.

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem.  Ya, it's gotta be only at 0.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right, I should have phrased it as wavelength.  That was dumb.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Ok, now that I'm using frequency in your equation, everything is popping out right so far.  Nice!

Comment: Actually, by accident or not, this has turned out to be precisely what I wanted.  I wanted to catch it when the cycles of the sine aligned, which it turns out is only half of the times the sine crosses 0.  I've turned your equation into this: x = ((start0 * wavelength1) - (start1 * wavelength0)) % LCM, and it appears to be working exactly as needed despite all sorts of wave crossings in a plot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17619/discussion-between-airza-and-user173342)

Answer (score 2):

For each wave generate the list of times at which the wave is 0; take the intersection of the lists; take the earliest time from the intersection.  Need it be any more complicated than that ?  I guess you'll want to generate only a finite number of elements in each list, unless you have a system which can deal with infinite data structures.

The other approach would be to write the terms of each wave as arithmetic series, in your example `(1+3m)` and `(0+4n)` and solve the equation

`(1+3m)-(0+4n) == 0`

which will have infinite solutions.  But if you set `m==1` then `n==1`; if you set `m==2` then there are no solutions with integer `n`.  It would be easy enough to write a little function in your favourite language to spit out the integer solutions one-by-one.

And a little more algebra shows that, for the example given, the sequence of `(m,n)` values is `(1,1),(5,4),(9,7), ...,(m,n),(m+4,n+3),...`.

As before, I'm leaving as an exercise to the interested party to generalise this.